# How to store an integer in an activity for calculation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, calculator

I'm currently creating an application that adds together values to give an overall total, like so.  oldValue + newValue = textView1...

MainActivity, this is where the overall value is to be stored in textView1

```
 String calorie = getIntent().getStringExtra("calorie");
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String strOldValue = textView1.getText().toString();

        Integer oldValue;
        try{
            oldValue= Integer.parseInt(myString);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            oldValue =0;
        }

        Integer newValue;
        try{
            newValue= Integer.parseInt(calorie);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            newValue =0;
        }
        textView1.setText((oldValue + newValue));
```

The problem is that the textview is forgetting the old value and just inserting the new value... so carry 100, then i go to add 150... and i'm only seeing 150. A believe i need to store the 100 (oldValue) somewhere. Any advice?

Context: This is a food calculator that adds food calories using an AddActivity, and a MainActivity.

Comment: what is myString here?

Comment: The code snippet is not showing from where the value of myString is coming.

Comment: A string carried from my AddActivity class holding the newValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity take a static variable

```
static int count=0;
```

and get value

```
String calorie = getIntent().getStringExtra("calorie");
```

and add it to

```
count+=Integer.parseInt(calorie);
```

and set the value to edittext

```
 textView1.setText(count+"");
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're assign oldValue in `oldValue= Integer.parseInt(myString);` it uses myString, when we need to use strOldValue, which you get here `String strOldValue = textView1.getText().toString();`
A problem is only of your inattention, good luck)

Comment: ah yes, although it still doesn't add the two values.